# How to reset mobile fingerprint

Tags: lenovo, fingerprint

How to reset mobile fingerprint?

**Mobile Model :  Lenovo vibe P1**

Comment: Go to settings > lockscreen > add fingerprint and delete all fingerprints after entering security pin

Comment: mobile is fingerprint locked now how to open the mobile?.

Comment: You always have the option to open it via security pin. So unlock it via pin

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the phone with security pin then go to settings > lockscreen > manage fingerprints

Input your security pin again and then delete all registered fingerprints.